# QGIS window can't be resized or exited and is displayed in Full-screen, only

Tags: qgis, display, windows-10

OS Windows10 Pro 64-bit
When I launch QGIS3.18, the window in which it displays takes over the whole extent of the monitor with no margins, hiding the application icons at the bottom of my screen.  The window can't be resized or even minimised. This problem only occurs with QGIS - other application are fine.  The only way I can view the menu icons again is by closing down QGIS.  I have tested with earlier versions of QGIS and the same problem occurs, even though it didn't when those earlier versions were current.  In fact it didn't happen with 3.18 at first. Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click `F11` or go to menu `view / toggle full screen mode`

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, JGH.  That solved it.